# Trigger event whenever validity changes in redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

In my React + Redux + Redux-Form app, I need to enable/disable a "Next" button depending on the validity state of the form. This button is controlled by the parent component, so I can't just have `<Button disabled={!props.valid}/>`. Ideally redux-form would give me an event like `onValidityChanged` that I could listen for, and call the `setCompleted()` function passed down by the parent component whenever this happens. However such an event doesn't seem to exist. I also can't use the `onChange` hook, because at this point it won't have access to the props passed by the parent.

e.g.

```
function Parent(props){
    const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Child setCompleted=setCompleted/>
            <button disabled={!completed}>Next</button>
        </div>
    );
}

const Child = reduxForm({form: 'form'})(props => {
    const {setCompleted} = props;

    // Call setCompleted once this form becomes valid
});
```

How can I run an event whenever the validity of the form changes, but still have access to props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way of doing so would be to read the current validity status as Redux-Form updates it in your redux state, using a selector. You can even use one provided by the `redux-form` package: `isValid`. Since you're using hooks, you can also use `react-redux`'s `useSelector` hook (if you're using react-redux v7.1.0 or higher).

The result would be:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux`;
import { reduxForm, isValid } from 'redux-form`;

const Child = reduxForm({form: 'form'})(props => {
    const { setCompleted } = props;
    const isFormValid = useSelector(state => isValid('form')(state));

    // Call setCompleted once this form becomes valid
    if (isFormValid) {
      setCompleted(true);
    }
});
```

Of course you may want to extract this selector in another file and memoize it.

You may also want to use this hook (or its `mapStateToProps` equivalent) directly inside the parent component to avoid using the `useState` hook in the first place.

Comment: Sadly if I do that it causes an infinite loop where it tells the parent it's valid, the parent `setCompleted`, and this re-renders the child.

Comment: But I managed to add a conditional to prevent the loop. Seems to work!